# Looping through a list of Google Calendar Users

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a list of Google Email users in a google sheet(named Master, column E). Each user also has a blank sheet named after that email address (User@Whatever.com).

What I'm aiming to do it go through the user list, retrieve the calendar entries for today for each user, and enter them into their relevant sheet. So far I have the following code, but it's returning

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getEventsForDay" of null. (line 15,
>   file "Calendar Update")

Code is below:

```
var employeeDataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("Master!E2:E");
var employeeObjects = employeeDataRange.getValues();

for (var j=0; j<employeeObjects.length; j++) {  
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(employeeObjects[j]);
    var sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(employeeObjects[j])
    var today = new Date();

    var events = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(cal).getEventsForDay(today);
    for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {    
        var details=[[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), events[i].getAllTagKeys()]];
        var row=i+1;
        var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,4);
        range.setValues(details);
    }
}  
}
```

Cheers,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have all permissions to see those calendars and their events?

Moreover, you have this row
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(employeeObjects[j]);
where employeeObjects[j] is the calendar id and cal is the relative calendar.
Two rows after you have
var events = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(cal).getEventsForDay(today);
but cal is a calendar, not its id. Why you don't use cal.getEventsForDay(today)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do have access to the calendars, and the bit that gets the event details works if I use just the email address.
I tried your example of using cal.getEventsforDay(today), but that didn't work either I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I Figured it out:

```
  var calendar = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("Master!E2:E");
var employeeObjects = calendar.getValues();

for (var j=0; j<employeeObjects.length; j++) {

var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(employeeObjects[j]);
var sheet =   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(employeeObjects[j])
var today = new Date();

 var events = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(employeeObjects[j]).getEventsForDay(today);
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {

var details=[[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), events[i].getAllTagKeys()]];
var row=i+1;
var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,4);
range.setValues(details);
}
}  
}
```